# Kotlin coroutines using produces and mockito to mock the producing job

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am testing Kotlin coroutines in my Android app and I am trying to do the following unit test

```
@Test fun `When getVenues success calls explore venues net controller and forwards result to listener`() = 
    runBlocking {
      val near = "Barcelona"
      val result = buildMockVenues()
      val producerJob = produce<List<VenueModel>>(coroutineContext) { result.value }
      whenever(venuesRepository.getVenues(eq(near))) doReturn producerJob // produce corooutine called inside interactor.getVenues(..)

      interactor.getVenues(near, success, error) // call to real method

      verify(venuesRepository).getVenues(eq(near))
      verify(success).invoke(argThat {
        value == result.value
      })
}
```

The interactor method is as follows

```
fun getVenues(near: String, success: Callback<GetVenuesResult>,
  error: Callback<GetVenuesResult>) =
postExecute {
  repository.getVenues(near).consumeEach { venues ->
    if (venues.isEmpty()) {
      error(GetVenuesResult(venues, Throwable("No venues where found")))
    } else {
      success(GetVenuesResult(venues))
    }
  }
}
```

`postExecute{..}` is a method on a `BaseInteractor` that executes the function in the ui thread through a custom Executor that uses the `launch(UI)` coroutine from kotlin android coroutines library

```
fun <T> postExecute(uiFun: suspend () -> T) =
  executor.ui(uiFun)
```

Then the `repository.getVenues(..)` function is also a coroutine that returns the ProducerJob using `produce(CommonPool) {}`

The problem is that it seams that success callback in the interactor function doesn't seem to be executed as per the

```
verify(success).invoke(argThat {
  value == result.value
})
```

However, I do see while debugging that the execution in the interactor function reaches to the `if (venues.isEmpty())` line inside the `consumeEach` but then from there exits and continues with the test, obviously failing on the verify for the success callback.

I am a bit new on coroutines so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't any asynchronous calls that are then part of the verification of a test likely to fail/pass based on the nature of it being non blocking/asynchronous? Maybe do the verification outside the `runBlocking {}` statement?

Comment: yes, I know that the suspendable function on the repository is asyncronous by nature but note that I am using the runBlocking coroutine in my test which from what I understand it makes the suspendable functions called inside it to run on the current thread? It could be that I am wrong, though

Comment: I suspect the calling thread is blocked, but not the coroutines themselves inside runBlocking. runBlocking is just like a Thread.join() call, from what the docs have to say - "We can use delay if we wrap it into runBlocking {} that starts a coroutine and waits until it's done:". I'd put some system time stamp logging to see when calls are being made - this will also verify suspendable function calls working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. I saw that the problem was just with this producing coroutine and not with the others tests that are also using coroutines and working just fine. I noticed that I actually missed the send on the mocked ProducingJob in order to have it actually produce a value, in this case the list of mocks. I just added that changing the mock of the producing job to

```
val producerJob = produce { send(result.value) }
```